# 3D table tennis physics part?

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, physics

I'm trying to program a 3D table tennis game using xna. I've got the models up but now finding it hard to implement the physics part of the game.  I know that there are quite a few physics engines out there, but which would be the best for my game, or if there is a physics engine that tackled 3D table tennis? Or should I try to implement my own physics? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a physic library just for tennis.
You have to just look at the physics behind a ball bouncing in a table.

http://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/bouncing-ball-physics.html